# How to fix: loop with dataframe name

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I want to create some plots with random numbers in a loop. I want to save the created numbers in separate dataframes for example `df1, df2 or df3` but it apparently always overwrites it.

How can I use the `i` for the dataframes names?

```
x1 <- c(1:9)
   for (i in 1:3)
   {
     name = paste("Pic_", i, ".png", sep="")
     png(name)
     x2 <- rnorm(9,2,2)
     plot(x1,x2)
     df <- data.frame(x1,x2)
     dev.off()
    }
```

Comment: `paste` is vectorized.  You don't need a loop  `paste("Pic_", 1:3, ".png", sep="")`

Comment: instead of dataframes with different names you can use a list of dataframes: `df=list();` `df[[i]] = `

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for (i in 1:3){
  x1<-1:9
  assign(paste("df",i,sep = ""), rnorm(9,2,2))
  png(paste("Pic_", i, ".png", sep=""))
  plot(x1,get(paste("df",i,sep = "")),ylab=paste("df",i,sep = ""))
  dev.off()
}
```

The assign and get functions are important here. Assign creates a name in the environment, which is needed to create dataframes with different names using "i". The get function allows you to search for the dataframes you create again using "i" to search for the correct one. Both use the paste function to allow "i" to change with each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Considering adding more explanation.  Explaining your answer will help those that come back later looking at this question/answer to understand better how your answer solves the question being asked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Hope these my edits help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work - you end up with a list of three data frames.
By using `df.list[[i]]` you're addressing the index `i`.

```r
x1 <- c(1:9)
df.list <- list()
for (i in 1:3) {
  name = paste("Pic_", i, ".png", sep="")
  png(name)
  x2 <- rnorm(9, 2, 2)
  plot(x1, x2)
  df.list[[i]] <- data.frame(x1, x2)
  dev.off()
}
```

Each item of the list is a data frame, accessed like you would any other list object:

```r
> is.data.frame(df.list)
[1] FALSE
> is.data.frame(df.list[[1]])
[1] TRUE
```